# How to show that $Im(f) = B$ iff $f$ is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f : A → B$

My teacher said  that $\text{Im}(f)=\{f(b):b\in A\} = B$ iff $f$ is onto. I know that this statement is true because it is kind of obvious but is there a way to prove it?

Comment: In my book, that's the _definition_ of onto. What about yours?

Comment: how is this related to continuity?

Comment: It is a tautology…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is surjective (onto), meaning that for each $b \in B$ there exists an $a \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$.

Suppose first that $f$ is surjective, we show that $\text{Im}(f) = B$. Since $f$ is surjective for each $b \in B$, $\exists a \in A$ such that $b = f(a)$. Hence $f[A] = \text{Im}(f) = B$

Conversely suppose $\text{Im}(f) = B$ we show that $f$ is surjective. We have that $f[A] = \text{Im}(f) = B$, hence for each $b \in B$ there exists and $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$, which is the definition of surjectivity (onto). $\square$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{HINT}$ $:$ Try to prove that $Im(f)$ $\subseteq$ $B$ and $B$ $\subseteq$ $Im(f)$.